# Using Sampler3D to read from a 3D texture in OpenGL ES 3.x

Tags: opengl-es, 3d-texture, opengl-es-3.1

I am using OpenGL ES 3.2 to read from a 3D texture in the fragment shader and write that value out to an FBO. I then read from the FBO attachment using glReadPixels, and print out the values obtained.

I am attaching the sampler as:

```
GLuint texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program_new, "input_tex");
glUniform1i(texLoc, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, texture_output);
```

Inside the shader, I read from the texture as:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
precision highp sampler3D;
    
uniform sampler3D input_tex;
in vec3 tex_pos;
out vec4 fragmentColor;
    
void main() {
    fragmentColor = texture(input_tex, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)); // nonzero z co-ordinate doesn't work    
}
```

While reading from the texture, I am only able to read from values where the z co-ordinate is 0. Reading values from any other depths gives garbage values or NANs.

Shouldn't a 3D texture allow me to use (x, y, z) values as texture co-ordinates, where x, y, and **even z** can be between 0.0 and 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess: You didn't initialize the texture correctly.
Please show the texture creation code.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the 3D texture not being bound as layered.

Take a look at this: [Compute shader not modifying 3d texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015132/compute-shader-not-modifying-3d-texture/17055309)